# IIS - Allow IP range for a web application

Tags: .net, iis

I want to allow IP range to access my application on IIS. This IP range is owned by third party provider which sends me callback requests. They gave me an IP range to allow. This IP range is XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24. How should I fill these values to allow this range?

[image]

Comment: https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html Calculate mask from prefix, and then you can edit XML directly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add#configuration-sample

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

To create a rule for a range of IP addresses, select the IP address range, and enter the subnet and subnet mask in the provided textboxes. For example, to permit access to all IP addresses in the range from 192.168.8.0 to 192.168.8.8 then enter the subnet as 192.168.8.0 and subnet mask as the 255.0.0.0.

To calculate the subnet mask you could use the subnet mask online calculator it is easy to use and get the exact value:

https://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/subnetmask-calculator.php

If you do not have much idea about the subnet mask and its configuration you could use the iis URL rewrite rule by following below steps:

1)First, download and install iis URL rewrite extension from the below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2)Open iis manager and select your site.

3)From the pane, double-click the URL Rewrite icon.

[image]

4)On the URL Rewrite pane, on the Actions section in the upper right corner, click Add Rule(s) to create the first rule (i.e. to allow internal access).

[image]

5)add the blank rule as shown below:

[image]

6)Now click on apply go back and click on add rule.

7)Click on the requests blocking rule:

[image]

8) In the Add Request Blocking Rule dialog, select IP Address from the Block access based on dropdown

Select Matches the Pattern from the Block request that dropdown

Enter the first internal Pattern (IP Address) to allow, using " * " (asterisk) to enable a wildcard

Select Wildcards from the Using dropdown, if enabling wildcards

Click OK

[image]

Click ok and refresh your site.

your rule will look like below in web.config file:

```
<rule name="Allow rule" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="159.247.25.*" />
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.1.*.*" />
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
            </rule>
```

for more detail please refer below link:

[IP Address and Domain Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831785(v=ws.11))

[IIS ban IP range](https://serverfault.com/questions/435690/iis7-ban-ip-range)

[Understanding TCP/IP addressing and subnetting basics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164015/understanding-tcp-ip-addressing-and-subnetting-basics)

Comment: Great answer, but am I missing something or the subnet mask in your example should be 255.255.255.240 ?

Comment: Great answer, but in the Above Step 5 "Edit Inbound Rule" you're showing that the rule has "Match All", it should be "Match Any".  Match All would require it to match every address in the list, which would fail unless there is a single address.